# Mounting a Linux distro iso under OS X El Capitan

Tags: linux, macos, mount, iso-image

I need to access a few files which are part of a linux distro iso that I've downloaded. I can't install the distro so I was wanting to mount it if that's possible under Mac OS X.

I found a guide that suggested just double clicking the iso but I get the error "No mountable file systems"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears the issue is with the way the iso was created.

Here is an answer from the Ask Ubuntu site.

https://askubuntu.com/a/153909

> Since 11.10, Ubuntu ISOs have been "hybrid", meaning that the ISO can
>   also be written bit-for-bit to a USB device to make it a working
>   Live-USB, without having to use StartUp Disk Creator, UNetBootin, etc.
>
> Note that this "hybrid" is different from the OS X/Disk Utility
>   definition of "hybrid", which simply refers to an ISO readable on both
>   Mac (HFS+) and Windows (ISO9660).
>
> Ubuntu's hybrid functionality is
>   provided by the isohybrid script in the SysLinux bootloader. It works
>   by encapsulating the standard ISO9660 CD filesystem within a
>   partition, so that it will work unmodified if written to a USB/hard
>   disk.

So I wasn't able to mount the iso in the way I was wanting however I did find a file extraction tool called [Keka](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/index.php) that allowed me to extract the distro iso and then browse the filesystem. Which was the next best thing.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 13):

I was having some trouble with this whilst trying to install [Arch Linux via PXE](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PXE). I found a working answer [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30019723#message30019723), which can be summed up as follows:

```
❯ mkdir arch-mount

❯ hdiutil attach -nomount archlinux-2017.05.01-x86_64.iso
/dev/disk2              FDisk_partition_scheme          
/dev/disk2s2            0xEF

❯ mount -t cd9660 /dev/disk2 arch-mount
```

Comment: Still working with Monterey +1.